# anyString() in mockito is throwing an invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito

I am using eclipse to run some unit tests on a class and I am using Mockito so I don't have to connect to the database. I have used anyString() in other tests which works but it isn't working in this test. If I change it from anyString() to "" the error disappears and the test passes.

My test is:

```
@Test
public void test_GetUserByUsername_CallsCreateEntityManager_WhenAddUserMethodIsCalled() {

    //Arrange
    EntityManagerFactory mockEntityManagerFactory = mock(EntityManagerFactory.class);
    EntityManager mockEntityManager= mock(EntityManager.class);
    UserRepositoryImplementation userRepositoryImplementation = new UserRepositoryImplementation();
    userRepositoryImplementation.setEntityManagerFactory(mockEntityManagerFactory);

    when(mockEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(mockEntityManager);


    //Act
    userRepositoryImplementation.getUserByUsername(anyString());

    //Assert
    verify(mockEntityManagerFactory, times(1)).createEntityManager();

}
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting the error and what I can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
userRepositoryImplementation.getUserByUsername(anyString());
```

This is not the right use of `anyString()`.
It can be used for stubbing or for verifying. But not for actual call of method.
From [documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html):

> Allow flexible verification or stubbing.

If you want a random string when test is running try to use [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) or any other similar library.

```
userRepositoryImplementation.getUserByUsername(RandomStringUtils.random(length));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Matchers`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html), like `anyString()` for mocking up (stubbing) an object. I.e. inside a `when()` invocation. Your invocation is an actual invocation:

```
//Act
userRepositoryImplementation.getUserByUsername(anyString());
```

So that's right: for testing you have to add some real input, like `""`, `"salala"` or `null`.